# iPhone: Memory Leak in Custom Class and NSMutableDictionary

Tags: iphone, memory-leaks, nsmutabledictionary

I've spent a couple of days trying to find out what's going on. I have read loads of Memory Management documentation and I am sick to death of hearing "for every alloc you need a release" - I know that and I still can't figure out why my code is producing memory leaks.

I am writing a simple custom class with an NSMutableDictionary as one of its properties. Basically it mimics an XMLELement. I cannot for the life of me figure out why the allocation of a dictionary is causing a memory leak. The leak occurs on the device as well as the simulator - 5 leaks on the device, and 20 on the simulator.

The leak occurs when I declare and allocate the variable *tmp.
There is also a leak when I set the attribute details (name and value).

This is driving me nuts. Please help!

Part of the code:

```
@interface IMXMLElement : NSObject {

NSString *strElementName;
NSString *strElementValue;
NSMutableDictionary *dictAttributes;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *strElementName;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *strElementValue;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableDictionary *dictAttributes;

@end

@implementation IMXMLElement

@synthesize strElementName;  
@synthesize strElementValue;  
@synthesize dictAttributes;

-(id)initWithName:(NSString *)pstrName
{
    self = [super init];

    if (self != nil)
    {
        self.strElementName = pstrName;
        **LEAK NSMutableDictionary *tmp = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
        self.dictAttributes = tmp;
        [tmp release];
    }

    return self;
}

-(void)setAttributeWithName:(NSString *)pstrAttributeName  
andValue:(NSString *)pstrAttributeValue  
{  
    **LEAK [self.dictAttributes setObject:pstrAttributeValue forKey:pstrAttributeName];  
}

-(void)dealloc
{
    [strElementName release];
    [strElementValue release];
    [dictAttributes release];
    [super dealloc];    
}
```

The access this class using the following code:

`NSString *strValue = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"Test Value"];`

```
IMXMLElement *xmlElement = [[IMXMLElement alloc] initWithName:@"Test_Element"];
[xmlElement setAttributeWithName:@"id" andValue:strValue];
```

Comment: Do not use `retain` for `NSString` properties. Use `copy`

Comment: OK - I ran the instruments leak tool gave me a red herring. The problem was me not releasing xmlElement and strValue when I was calling my class. I found this out after running Build and Analyze.

Thanks for any comments though.

The instruments tool pointed to the lines I stated as leaks.
Also, the device noted less leaks than the Simulator. Apple needs to run a proper leak analyzer on the Insturments Tool (for simulator).

Comment: I do have another question. Who owns the responsibility to release a dictionary object called using the abstract method call 
NSDictionary *mydictionary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithCapacity]?

I will give the answer to the anyone who answers this

Comment: @snow888 the returned object would be autoreleased in that case. Also, there is no such thing as an abstract method in Objective-C.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you have strings as properties, declare them as copy, not retain.

```
  NSMutableDictionary *tmp = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
  self.dictAttributes = tmp;
  [tmp release];
```

the above is unnecessary, instead do:
*(retain count will automatically be incremented for this autorelease object)*

```
self.dictAttributes = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithCapacity:0];
```

in dealloc do:
*(retain count will automatically be decremented)*

```
self.dictAttributes = nil;
```

normally for properties you just set them to nil instead of explicitly releasing them
since the get/setter handles that for you.

Comment: What is the reason for not declaring a property of type NSString using retain?

Comment: because you can assign a NSMutableString to the property, meaning the original string may after the assignment be altered - so its better to take a one time copy of it to prevent weird errors.

Answer (score 0):

Try [dictAttributes removeAllObjects] before releasing dictAttributes.

Edit:

Also, you will positive allocation because you are allocating memory for "tmp". The memory will be retained because you now have a reference from dictAttributes.

You then have more positive allocation when you add elements to the dictionary, which also need to be allocated and are kept in memory by the dictionary's internal references

Comment: Good idea - I assumed that when you release an NSDictionary, all its objects are freed as well - as per NSArray.

Answer (score 0):

Typical syntax is `NSMutableDictionary *tmp = [[[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init] autorelease];`

Comment: Not necessarily. This alloc/init/assign-to-property/release pattern is common, especially in Apple sample code.

Comment: I read somewhere that autorelease should not be used for iPhone projects - is this correct? I mean, there is no knowing when the object will be released and it could be released when you need it (especially when returning objects from functions/methods.

Comment: The Apple documentation says you shouldn't use autorelease, but the rest of the documentation is riddled with it.